# VBA to compare rows and highlight differences in the same worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

There is a weekly process that is done to compare data from two different sources. The data is already put together in one worksheet. I have to review this worksheet and highlight differences within 2 rows for each employee.

In total, there is data from Column A through J starting in Row 4. So I need to compare Row 4 to 5, Row 6 to 7 and so on... and highlight all of the discrepancies/differences.  I also only want to compare Columns C through J instead of A through J as this data is always different as it is pulled from two different sources.

Issues that I have run into so far....

1. I am not sure how to create a loop and only hit on the columns I want to compare - C:J - instead of selecting each set of ranges
2. If there is more than 1 difference per two rows only the first difference is highlighted

Here is what I have tried to do:

```
Sub HighlightDiff()
 Range("C4:J5").Select
 Selection.ColumnDifferences(ActiveCell).Select
 Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0)).Select
 Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = 6

 Range("C6:J7").Select
 Selection.ColumnDifferences(ActiveCell).Select
 Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0)).Select
 Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
End Sub
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: So glad that your question popped up when I was composing mine! I have almost the same problem, but want to compare variable numbers of rows grouped/specified by a column. This is certainly a helpful starting point!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```vb
Sub HighlightDiff()
    Dim rng As Range, rngDiff As Range
    Set rng = Range("C4:J5")              'start here
    Do While Application.CountA(rng) > 0  'loop while have content
        Set rngDiff = Nothing   'reset range
        On Error Resume Next    'ignore "No cells were found" error if no differences
        Set rngDiff = rng.ColumnDifferences(Comparison:=rng.Cells(1))
        On Error GoTo 0         'stop ignoring errors
        If Not rngDiff Is Nothing Then 
            rngDiff.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 'color all differences
            rngDiff.Offset(-1).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        End If 
        Set rng = rng.Offset(2) 'two rows down
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Tim, very helpful. Thank you! I did change 1 thing:

```
If Not rngDiff Is Nothing Then rngDiff.Offset(-1, 0).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
```
I modified this line as I would rather highlight the top cell vs the bottom cell. Highlighting both would be great but I can settle for this. I do also prefer the yellow highlight vs vbRed. Thank you for your help!!

Comment: If you want to highlight both rows you can use both `rngDiff.Offset(-1, 0).Interior.ColorIndex = 6` and `rngDiff.Interior.ColorIndex = 6`  See update above.

Comment: Thanks, Tim, for the very helpful answer! Knowing nothing about VBA, I wonder whether it's possible to generalise this solution for various numbers of rows, because I have a similar sheet containing grades of several sites (columns) given by variable numbers of surveyors (rows) each day. I have posted my question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69583783/automatically-compare-rows-grouped-by-a-column-and-highlight-different-cells-in, if it's difficult to explain in the comment. Many thanks in advance!