# Automatically compare rows grouped by a column and highlight different cells in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Suppose I have a spreadsheet containing grades of several sites given by variable numbers of surveyors each day:

| date | site_a_grade | site_b_grade | site_c_grade |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10-01 | 5 | 4 | 4 |
| 2021-10-01 | 5 | 3 | 4 |
| 2021-10-02 | 5 | 4 | 3 |
| 2021-10-02 | 5 | 4 | 4 |
| 2021-10-02 | 4 | 4 | 4 |
| 2021-10-03 | 5 | 4 | 4 |

Is it possible to automatically compare daily scores from all surveyors for each site and highlight the different cells with colour for easy viewing? For example, the two `site_b_grade` for 2021-10-01 are different, so they could be highlighted in amber for review. Now I'd like to do this for the whole sheet automatically.

I found a similar question on [VBA to compare rows and highlight differences in the same worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68775827/vba-to-compare-rows-and-highlight-differences-in-the-same-worksheet), where the OP wanted to compare 2 adjacent rows. I guess it's possible to generalise the solution to specify a grouping column, but I don't know VBA, so kind help will be appreciated!

Comment: Thanks, FaneDuru, for your comment. I never thought of SO as a free-coding-service site - I see it as a friendly and inclusive community. Having distanced myself from Excel to R, I tried conditional formatting in Excel but couldn't solve it by myself; I searched SO, studied the relevant question and answer as much as I can, and posted my question with a reproducible example and reference to the other post - aren't these my "research" and efforts? I love learning, but Rome wasn't built in a day, so isn't learning VBA. I believe everyone has their limit, and being honest about it isn't wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need VBA for this, you can get it done using conditional formatting.

For Example if your sample data above is in range `A1:D7`, then you can use the following formula on range `B2:D7` (excluding headers and 1st column)

```
=VLOOKUP($A2,$A$1:$D$7,COLUMN(B2)-COLUMN($A2)+1,FALSE)<>B2
```

This will highlight all the occurrences which do not match the first occurance

Note that the `$` symbols are really important

Sample Screenshot:
[image: Sample Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks very much, Gangula, for your prompt answer - using VLOOKUP to retrieve the first grade for each site on each day and comparing it with the other grades is a brilliant idea! I learnt two new things today. :)